# Dynamically change the tab labels in a CPropertySheet

Tags: c++, mfc, cpropertysheet

I want to instantiate 2 property pages from the same class and template, because the settings they show are basically the same.

```
CCPUSettingsSheet sheet;
CCPUSettingsPage cpucore1, cpucore2;
sheet.AddPage(&cpucore1);
sheet.AddPage(&cpucore2);
```

The only problem is that they get the same tab label text, which is the caption field in their resource template. I need to assign a different text to each one, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `CCPUSettingsPage` derives from [CPropertyPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/491c89bk.aspx), you can use its public [m_psp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/867zk9f2.aspx) member to access its underlying [PROPSHEETPAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774548.aspx) structure. From there, you can write something like:

```
cpucore1.m_psp.dwFlags |= PSP_USETITLE;
cpucore1.m_psp.pszTitle = "First Tab";

cpucore2.m_psp.dwFlags |= PSP_USETITLE;
cpucore2.m_psp.pszTitle = "Second Tab";
```